# Mathematically rigorous way to describe two vectors that have the same components but are not equal.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

In linear algebra, we're taught that vectors can be represented as the addition of a scalar multiplication of the basis vectors. For instance, if $\hat \imath, \hat \jmath$ are the unit vectors, $$\vec v = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{bmatrix} = v_1\hat \imath + v_2\hat \jmath$$ Is it possible that some vector $\vec v_*$ also be equal to $\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{bmatrix}$ but that their expression in terms of the basis makes it such that $\vec v \neq \vec v_*$, for example if the latter has a different basis s.t. $\vec v_* = v_1\hat r + v_2\hat p$? What exactly is the proper description of this situation? I don't think it is enough to say that they have different bases, since maybe we could build one basis from the other. Are they failing to share the same vector space, or something of the sort? Do we have to declare some property of $\vec v_*$ from the beginning?

I'm thinking this situation can arise if the vectors use different coordinate systems, but how can I describe this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> vectors can be represented as the addition of a scalar multiplication
>   of the basis vectors.

I think what you mean is that a vector can be expressed as a linear combination of basis vectors (if a basis for our vector space has been given).

Let $\beta_1 = (\hat i, \hat j)$ be an ordered basis of $\mathbb R^2$, and let $\beta_2 = (\hat r, \hat p)$ be some other ordered basis of $\mathbb R^2$. If a vector $v$ can be expressed as
$$
v = v_1 \hat i + v_2 \hat j
$$
then the coordinate vector of $v$ with respect to the basis $\beta_1$ is $\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{bmatrix}$. Another way to write this is:
$$
[ v ]_{\beta_1} = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
And if $v^* = v_1 \hat r + v_2 \hat p$, then the coordinate vector of $v^*$ with respect to $\beta_2$ is $\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{bmatrix}$.

Of course, this does not mean that $v = v^*$. All it means is that the coordinate vector of $v$ with respect to the basis $\beta_1$ happens to be the same as the coordinate vector of $v^*$ with respect to $\beta_2$.

Comment: This seems to be exactly it. Some clarifications before accepting the answer: we typically suppose that the coordinate vector of a vector is expressed with respect to the standard basis, right?

Comment: When we discuss the coordinate vector of $v$ with respect to a given basis, we always have to say which basis we're referring to. (If we don't say this explicitly, we are being careless.) It happens to be the case that if $\beta$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb R^2$, and $v \in \mathbb R^2$, then $[ v ]_\beta = v$.

Comment: I see, and the coordinate vector is what we typically call the expression of a vector resembling a column matrix? That is, a vector and it's coordinate vector are not the same?

Comment: It turns out that if $v$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^n$, then the coordinate vector of $v$ with respect to the standard basis is just $v$ itself. But that is just a peculiar little thing that happens when we're working in $\mathbb R^n$. In my mind, the elements of $\mathbb R^n$ are column vectors.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, this clears it up!

Answer (score 1):

Given a vector space $V$ and let a vector $v\in V$.

Let there are two ordered basis sets $U=\{u_1,u_2,...u_n\}$ and $W=\{w_1,w_2,...w_n\}$ and let the representation of $v$ in ordered basis $U$ and $W$ be $$[v]_U=\begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\.\\.\\.\\c_n \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$[v]_W=\begin{bmatrix} c'_1 \\ c'_2 \\.\\.\\.\\c'_n \end{bmatrix}$$

Which basically means $v=c_1u_1+c_2u_2+...c_nu_n$ and $v=c'_1w_1+c'_2w_2+...c'_nw_n$

Now, you are asking the relation between $[v]_U$ and $[v]_W$.

Now, $$[v]_W=A_{U\rightarrow W}[v]_U$$ where $A_{U\rightarrow W}$ is a matrix called the transition matrix and $(A_{U\rightarrow W})^{-1}=A_{W\rightarrow U}$

PS: I can discuss the method of finding the transition matrix if you want it.

Comment: This answer is also exactly what I'm looking for. Would it be appropriate to say that $c_1, c_2, ..., c_n$ = $c'_1, c'_2, ..., c'_n$ ?

Comment: @shintuku in general no

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, the answer was worthy of being accepted.

Comment: @shintuku Glad it helped. The other answer was more detailed and from a more experienced person. (He is a maths prof whereas I'm an undergrad and read this for the first time last month) :-)